# How to access Java enums from Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, enums

I develop JSF 2.x project with JRE 1.8 library. I create some Java enums and use them in related Java classes;

```
package deviceAndRegionManagement;

public enum ProtocolTypeEnum {
// If you add a new lookup type, you need to add it below.
PROT1(1201), 
PROT2(1202),
PROT3(1203),
PROT4(1204);

private int value;

private ProtocolTypeEnum(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
}

public static ProtocolTypeEnum parse(int value){
    for (ProtocolTypeEnum type : ProtocolTypeEnum.values())
        if (value == type.getValue())
            return type;
    return null;
}
}
```

However, I don't know how to access and use them in Javascript. I need your solutions.

**EDIT:**

I use Java enums in this way;

```
ProtocolTypeEnum pTypeEnum = ProtocolTypeEnum.parse(value);
switch (pTypeEnum) {
        case PORT1:
            ...;
            break;
        case PORT2:
            ...;
            break;
        case PORT3:
            ...;
            break;
        case PORT4:
            ...;
        default:
            break;
}
```

I want to use these enums in javascript in similar way;

```
switch (pTypeEnum) {
case PORT1:
    ...;
    break;
case PORT2:
    ...;
    break;
case PORT3:
    ...;
    break;
default:
    ...;
    break;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript running where?

Comment: Could you please add some "expected" Javascript to your question? I.e. what would it have looked like if it was straightforward? (This is just to make the question easier to understand)

Comment: What makes you think you can access them from Javascript?

Comment: I updated my question based on your requests.

Comment: @Pointy, javascript runs on clientside (chrome or any other browser).

Comment: JavaScript != Java. JavaScript doesn't have a concept of enums (unless you write your own).

Comment: @séan35 your Java environment is your **web server**, not the client. If you're communicating with the client, you're doing it via HTTP, and everything turns into a string.

Comment: I see something on internet about it. But, I do not understand and apply it. for ex; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974548/how-to-access-java-enums-from-javascript-java-1-8

Comment: @séan35 that question is about using JavaScript via the ScriptEngine facility *on the server*.

Comment: All in all, I understand that I have to create javascript constants instead of java enums, because I do not want to pass such values from server to client. Thanks for your contributions!